# Какой паттерн здесь можно применить?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть код, где много однотипных методов, отличающихся лишь типом объекта. Например:

```
foreach ($this->data as $index => $currentPoint) {
    $buildCanStart = false;
    $points = [];

    if ($this->isObject1CanStart($currentPoint, $index)) {
        $newPoint = $this->getNewSetupPoint(self::P1_NAME, self::P1_PRIORITY, $currentPoint);
        array_push($points, $newPoint);
        $buildCanStart = true;
    }

    if ($this->isObject2CanStart($currentPoint, $index)) {
        $newPoint = $this->getNewSetupPoint(self::P2_NAME, self::P2_PRIORITY, $currentPoint);
        array_push($points, $newPoint);
        $buildCanStart = true;
    }

    if ($this->isObject3CanStart($currentPoint, $index)) {
        $newPoint = $this->getNewSetupPoint(self::P3_NAME, self::P3_PRIORITY, $currentPoint);
        array_push($points, $newPoint);
        $buildCanStart = true;
    }

    if ($this->isObject4CanStart($currentPoint, $index)) {
        $newPoint = $this->getNewSetupPoint(self::P4_NAME, self::P4_PRIORITY, $currentPoint);
        array_push($points, $newPoint);
        $buildCanStart = true;
    }

    if ($buildCanStart) {
        usort($points, function($a, $b) {
            return $b['priority'] - $a['priority'];
        });
        
        $this->hierarchy = array_merge($this->hierarchy, $points);
        
        continue;
    }
    
    $this->buildObject($currentPoint, $index);
}
```

Есть также методы `buildObj1/buildObj2/buildObj2`| `needInterruptObj1/needInterruptObj2/needInterruptObj3`

В общем я хочу сделать отдельные объекты для них и общий класс, с абстрактными методами, чтобы эти классы переопределили и описали логику там. В основном же файле, вызывать методы этого класса.

Всё бы ничего, но в методах `isObject1CanStart/isObject2CanStart/isObject3CanStart...` не к чему привязаться, чтобы однозначно обратиться к методу конкретного объекта.

**Однако в других методах, в т.ч. buildObj1  МОЖНО БУДЕТ однозначно идентифицировать объект, т.к. он будет заноситься с именем P1_NAME/P2_NAME/и т.д.**

Ничего лучше я не придумал, как где-либо создать список с объектами, положить её в переменную  типа такого:

```
public function getAllObjects() {
    return [
        new Object1(),
        new Object2(),
        new Object3(),
        ...
    ];
}
```

А потом в цикле проходиться по ним и вызывать метод `canStart()`.

Нормальный это подход или что-то можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Я бы применил Стратегия . https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Behavioral/Strategy/README.html